# installp command device /dev/rdf0 could not be accessed

Tags: aix

I am trying to install with the "installp"  command on AIX 6.1 as following

```
installp -agXYD . Java71.jre Java71.sdk 2>&1 | tee installp.log
```

while I am located in a directory where the Java71.jre and Java71.sdk files are located, however i get the following error:

```
installp:  Device /dev/rfd0 could not be accessed.
    Specify a valid device name.
```

Any ideas where can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told the `installp` command which device the filesets reside on; by default, installp assumes they reside on /dev/rfd0, which is where it looked, and which it couldn't access.

Add the `-d` flag to point to the current directory, if that's where the filesets are:

```
installp -agXYD -d. Java71.jre Java71.sdk 2>&1 | tee installp.log
```

Reference: [man installp](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/i_commands/installp.html)